# clojure-protobuf - Cannot run program [path protoc] (in directory "resources/proto"): error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: clojure, protocol-buffers

I am trying use clojure-protobuf, but when I run lein protobuf I get this error:

```
 >  /Users/elf/.lein/cache/lein-protobuf/protobuf-2.3.0/src/protoc google/protobuf/descriptor.proto --java_out=/Users/elf/.lein/cache/lein-protobuf/protobuf-2.3.0/java/src/main/java -I. -I/Users/elf/workspace/tmp/protobuf/target/proto -I/Users/elf/workspace/tmp/protobuf/resources/proto
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/elf/.lein/cache/lein-protobuf/protobuf-2.3.0/src/protoc" (in directory "resources/proto"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
    at conch.core$proc.doInvoke(core.clj:27)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at leiningen.protobuf$compile_protobuf.invoke(protobuf.clj:127)
    at leiningen.protobuf$compile_google_protobuf.invoke(protobuf.clj:145)
    at leiningen.protobuf$compile.doInvoke(protobuf.clj:154)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:139)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at leiningen.protobuf$compile.invoke(protobuf.clj:150)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at leiningen.protobuf$protobuf.doInvoke(protobuf.clj:166)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at leiningen.core.main$resolve_task$fn__3029.doInvoke(main.clj:189)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:410)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
    at clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke(AFunction.java:29)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619)
    at leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke(main.clj:230)
    at leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke(main.clj:234)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__3092.invoke(main.clj:303)
    at leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke(main.clj:290)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:415)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
    at clojure.main$main_opt.invoke(main.clj:335)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:440)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:423)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 48 more
in /Users/elf/workspace/tmp/protobuf
```

My `project.clj`

```
(defproject protocolbuf-test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.flatland/protobuf "0.7.1"]
                 [aleph "0.4.0-beta3"]
                 [lamina "0.5.6"]
                 [gloss "0.2.4"]]

  :plugins [[lein-protobuf "0.4.2"]])
```

and my proto file:

```
message Log {
                required int32 id = 1;
                required string event = 2;
}
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Hi @DanielCompton unfortunately I never come back to this problem. It was just some tests, nothing real.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in my case was that automake-1.14 wasn't installed. I had automake-1.15 installed, but that isn't sufficient. To reproduce this problem, I cd'd to `~/.lein/cache/lein-protobuf/protobuf-2.6.1` and ran `./configure && make` and it showed the error:

```
 cd . && /bin/sh /Users/me/.lein/cache/lein-protobuf/protobuf-2.6.1/missing automake-1.14 --foreign
/Users/me/.lein/cache/lein-protobuf/protobuf-2.6.1/missing: line 81: automake-1.14: command not found
WARNING: 'automake-1.14' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'Makefile.am' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'automake' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

I installed automake-1.14 with:

```
# Automake
echo "Installing automake-1.14 ..."
curl -fL https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/automake/automake-1.14.tar.gz | tar xzf -
cd automake-*
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make && sudo make install
[ $? -eq 0 ] && AUTOMAKE_ERROR=0 && cd .. && rm -rf automake-*
```

from https://gist.github.com/jellybeansoup/4192307#gistcomment-1676007